# Reducing overloading on both "const char*" and "const std::string&" arguments

Tags: c++, overloading

## Problem

I find the `c_str` member function of `std::basic_string` ugly, but at the same time I don't want the performance hit of creating lots of temporary `std::basic_string`.

### Example

For example, given these function signatures:

```
void foo(const char* s);

void bar(const std::string& s);
```

**Explicitly calling c_str**

If I have a `std::string` I must call the `c_str` member function explicitly at call site in order to call `foo`, which is a bit ugly.

```
std::string s = "...";
foo(s.c_str()); // Yuck! Ugly!
```

**Creating temporaries**

But if I already have a `const char*` the compiler needs to create a temporary `std::string` in order to call `bar`, which *may* involve a performance hit.

```
const char* s = "...";
bar(s); // Yuck! Potentially a performance hit!
```

**Overloading**

On the other hand, I could provide overloads for both and just forward the results from one to the other, but being lazy I don't want to write more code than needed.

```
void baz(const char* s);

// Yuck! Carpal tunnel syndrome imminent.
inline void baz(const std::string& s)
{
   baz(s.c_str());
}
```

## Requirements

So I think there is a better alternative which:

1. Would not require writing overloads.
2. Isn't that ugly on the function signature.
3. Would not involve a performance hit.
4. Would not involve writing (too much) extra code inside the functions.

### Possible alternatives

I thought that the [`boost::string_ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html), would help me here, but it is lacking a cheap way to convert to a `const char*`.

## Solution

So what I thought was to create a new class which would help me achieve this, something like this:

```
class c_str
{
public:
   c_str(const char* s)
      : s(s)
   {
   }

   c_str(const std::string& s)
      : s(s.c_str())
   {
   }

   operator const char*() const
   {
      return s;
   }

private:
   const char* s;
};

void qux(const c_str& s)
{
   std::string s1 = s;
   const char* s2 = s;
   std::cout << s;
}
```

**Usage**

```
foo("s1");

const char* s2 = "s2";
foo(s2);

const std::string s3 = "s3";
foo(s3);

foo(std::string("s4"));
```

Does a similar class already exist? Or is there an even better alternative?

EDIT: The problem escalate rather quickly if there are many string-like arguments. In my examples there are only one, but they can be many.

Comment: In client-facing library code, I just overload and live with the duplication. In internal code, I create whichever version(s) I need on the spot. Creating additional classes IMHO doesn't solve the fundamental problem, which is that C++ already has too many ways to denote a string.

Comment: I would suggest implementing both and using the `explicit` keyword to prevent type coersion and the unintentional creation of `string`s when they are not intended.

Comment: Your `c_str` class is basically just an old-fashioned C `char *`. But more dangerous, because it lulls you into a false sense of security. Before you know it you'll be holding `c_str`s pointing to long-gone strings...

Comment: Another option is to use `std::string` for all the strings you can, and not to use `char*` in function signatures.  You won't have the explicit-call-to-`c_str` problem, nor will you have the creating-temporaries problem (because you would not have declared `s` as `const char*`).

Comment: @DavidK yes, except that C++ string literals aren't std:strings. So whenever you use a string literal, there's the conversion.

Comment: The justification for *not* writing an overload for the few times this would *ever* be anything besides a brain-food issue: "but being lazy I don't want to write more code than needed", is contradictory to the "solution" of: "So what I thought was to create a new class...".

Comment: Would `&s[0]` not work with `string_ref` instead of a `c_str` member function, as long as you also pass around the length C style? I would use `string_ref`.

Comment: @Roddy: the "conversion" is the construction of the `std::string`. If you have a string literal, declare it `static const std::string` so it need be constructed only once per run.  The thing to avoid is repeatedly calling the constructor every time you pass that string literal to a function, which you might do many times in one run.

Comment: I have come to exactly the same solution, but with all these implicit constructors and conversion operators, I am getting ambiguity errors

Answer (score 2):

Do not underestimate the power of modern compilers. 
And always do profiling before thinking about optimizing code like that.

IMO, it is preferable to write clean,maintainable and safe code before writing optimized code by try to be more "intelligenter" than the libraries.

And if you have to have string (char* or std::string) operations to be optmized because it is the goal of your application to work with strings (large string data set), maybe you will need to find other type of containers (and/or string pools, ... ) for your particular usage.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `string_ref` is exactly there to solve this issue.

The problem with `char const*` is that there is no embedded length; a C-string ends at the first occurrence of a NUL character (`\0`) which means that whenever using `std::string::c_str` there is a risk that an embedded NUL character in the string means that the resulting C-string is only partially used by the client.

On the other hand `string_ref` embeds both a `char const*` and an *explicit* length and is thus suitable for the whole set of characters, comprising NUL. Therefore, the solution is to use `string_ref` if performance matters.

Of course, whether performance matters (at this call-site) or whether you actually get `char const*` in the first place is another story entirely. Normally, in C++, `char const*` is an oddity (your can use `std::string const` constants) and the only place `string_ref` really is interesting is for parsing (because lots of `substr` calls may have a performance impact, whereas just bumping an integer is cheap).